# Get values of bootstrap dropdown in php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form with multiple fields like input type name, checkboxes and also a dropdown. My code for dropdown:

```
<div class="container">
<form action="selecttest.php" method="post">
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="dropdown-toggle somename1" data-toggle="dropdown"id="menu1"></div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu myclass numberom1" aria-labelledby="menu1" name="thenumbers">
      <li value="one">One</li>
      <li value="two">Two</li>
      <li value="three">Three</li>
      <li value="four">Four</li>
      <li value="five">Five</li>
  </ul>

</div>
<input type="submit" name ="submit"/>
```

I want to get the value of the selected `<li>` in the selecttest.php. The following code is not working:

```
$val = $_POST["thenumbers"];
    echo "the Value selected is ".$val;
```

How can I get the value of the dropdown in the php page? There are other elements in the form as mentioned above so i cannot use jquery onclick event. And this is a non ajax form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A dropdown menu is not the same as a `select` input.

Within a form, the syntax for a `select` input (like yours, within Bootstrap) would be:

```
<label for="select_1">Select list:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="select_1" name="thenumbers">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
```

So long as the `select` has an attribute `name` with value "thenumbers", and the `select` is within the form that is being submitted, you will be able to get the value of the selected element in PHP with:

```
$val = $_POST["thenumbers"];
echo "the Value selected is ".$val;
```

---

To use the Bootstrap dropdown as a faux `select`, you can use JavaScript. Here is an example with jQuery:

*`HTML`*

```
<!-- Create dropdown and add specific class '.thenumbers' to ul element -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle somename1" data-toggle="dropdown"id="menu1"></div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu myclass numberom1 thenumbers" aria-labelledby="menu1" name="thenumbers">
        <li value="one">One</li>
        <li value="two">Two</li>
        <li value="three">Three</li>
        <li value="four">Four</li>
        <li value="five">Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Create a hidden input -->
<input type='hidden' name='thenumbers'>
```

*`jQuery`*

```
$(function(){
    //Listen for a click on any of the dropdown items
    $(".thenumbers li").click(function(){
        //Get the value
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        //Put the retrieved value into the hidden input
        $("input[name='thenumbers']").val(value);
    });
});
```

That way (as long as the hidden input is within the form), when the form is submitted, the "thenumbers" input value will be the last selected dropdown option.

Comment: So there is no way I can use the dropdown in Bootstrap as a form element yeah?

Comment: Not really - you can use JavaScript to alter an input based on a user clicking on a dropdown item, but you can also style a `select` box with CSS to look like a menu (which is much cleaner and easier!)

Comment: @Somename I've added a quick makeshift JavaScript solution.

Comment: I will try one for multiple selects by creating a array withing an object. Thanks for the logic. cheers!!!

Comment: but we should not forget to add hidden  input with name thenumbers in the html form.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is not submitting because there is no submit button.Try this code.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="selecttest.php" method="post">
<div class="dropdown" >

<select class="form-control" name="thenumbers">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>

</div>

 <input type="submit" name ="send"/>

</form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$val = $_POST["thenumbers"];
echo "the Value selected is ".$val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [Input group-bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/), you can get values in the PHP page by writing your code like this:

HTML/Bootstrap

```
<select name = "thenumbers" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <option value ="one" name ="one">One</option>
    <option value ="two" name ="two">Two</option>
    <option value ="three" name ="three">Three</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control border-secondary py-2" name="searchterm" type="text" >
     <div class="input-group-append">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value ="su       bmit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           </button>
     </div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['searchterm'])){
        if(isset($_POST['thenumbers']){
            $val = $_POST['thenumbers'];
            echo $val;
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the form element and use hyperlinks with url query string parameters. When a user clicks an option a GET request is made to the PHP file.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu myclass numberom1" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li><a href="<?php echo "selecttest.php?thenumbers=one" ?>">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo "selecttest.php?thenumbers=two" ?>">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo "selecttest.php?thenumbers=three" ?>">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo "selecttest.php?thenumbers=four" ?>">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo "selecttest.php?thenumbers=five" ?>">Five</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your PHP script, use `$_GET` to retrieve the query string variable.

```
$val = $_GET["thenumbers"];
echo "the Value selected is ".$val;
```