# access the value of bootstrap-select picker in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-selectpicker

> currently i was working with ajax jquery to post data to the php file, 
>   I use 'bootstrap selectpicker' to select list of guest which are loaded from the database

```
<select  name="guest_hidden_id" id="guest_hidden_id" 
  class="selectpicker form-control input-sm guest_hidden_id"  
  data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

> Below are javascript codes

```
    $("form#post-form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(event);          
        var formData = new FormData(this);          
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/add_booking.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {  
               alert(response);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;      
  });
```

> And below statement is how I capture the value

```
$guest_hidden_id = $_POST['guest_hidden_id'];   
  echo " Guest ID = ".$guest_hidden_id;
```

Comment: The option list are fine and they are loaded from database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get values of bootstrap dropdown in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900832/get-values-of-bootstrap-dropdown-in-php)

Comment: The code is fine when I remove "selectpicker" but its not working when the "selectpicker" is there

Comment: try to alert the value selected, Remember that bootstrap selector will not have the id of your <select> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long fight I realize that on removing the "data-tokens" attribute from the option list its work fine..!

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option value=".$row['guest_hidden_id']." data-tokens=".$row['guest_hidden_id'].">....</option>
</select>
```