# Getting Dropdown hidden id and get it using $_POST

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Dropdown made with bootstrap. I'm trying to take the id from the company the user has chosen to my $_POST method. In my table "empresas" I have two columns in it: 'id' and 'name';

This is my Dropdown code:

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"  style = "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >  Select the company <span class="caret"></span> </a>
         <?php
            require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT * from empresas") or die($conn->error);
            ?>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" aria-labelledby="drop4">
            <?php
               while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" name="idEmpresa" id = "idEmpresa" value = "<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" style="display:none;"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value = "<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?> </a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
   <button type="submit" name="addDataDep" class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn1">Adicionar</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is where i'll use the $_POST method:

```
if(isset($_POST['addDataDep'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $nomeDepartamento = $_POST['nomeDepartamento'];
    $id = $_POST['idEmpresa'];

    $_SESSION['message'] = "O departamento $idEmpresa foi adicionada com sucesso!";
}


require 'dbh.inc.php' already connects to my database.
```

When I try to $_POST it, it returns me this error: "Undefined index: idEmpresa".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If everything is going well and your post variable actually holds any value, then all you need to do is perform a normal select statement with a  `where` clause and use the id to fetch the specific row of data. I would suggest that you either study mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Actually, i forgot to say: it gives me an error. It returns this error: Undefined index: idEmpresa. So it's not finding the value. I dont really know why. My bad, forgot to write that.

Comment: Where exactly is that error? In your post variable? Could you highlight the line for me? The error is usually very specific and tells you exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: How are you posting this value? Narrowing down the error, the post variable never seems to be posted, or you're trying to fetch through the wrong index.

Comment: It gives me this error at line 27: Notice: Undefined index: nomeEmpresa

Line 27 is: $id = $_POST['idEmpresa'];

Comment: To post I use ```<form action="includes/add.inc.php" method="post">``` around the parts i want to post.

Comment: The id of the menu is menu1, not idEmpresa.

Comment: If I use menu1 in POST as in  $id = $_POST['menu1'] it gives me the same error :```Notice: Undefined index: menu1```

Comment: Also any specific reason why you are using `<ul>` as opposed to `<select>` ? You should strive to make your HTML as semantic as possible. I don't believe the form will pick up your `<ul>` nor its list items.

Comment: Actually not. Using select is better?

Comment: AHHHHH nervermind I totally see what you're trying now and what you meant by "hidden" etc. Now it all makes sense. What you're trying is to simply post the variable while keeping it as a hidden element in HTML, correct? So the semantics doesn't really matter, except it does to some degree. You shouldn't be using `<ul>`, you should use an input field, and don't give it `display: none;`. This will remove the element all-together, causing it to not be picked up by the form submit. Instead use `visibility: hidden;` as your CSS property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get values of bootstrap dropdown in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900832/get-values-of-bootstrap-dropdown-in-php)

Comment: FYI, your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and will undoubtedly be hacked if it hasn't been already.  Use parameterized queries to avoid this problem, by fundamentally separating the data from the query.

Comment: Martin and Shadow. The two answers worked! Thank you guys for the help! Really appreciate.

Comment: @Brad, This is for a dashboard. I don't really think admin would inject code in it. He already has all the data in his hands. Well, this is just my thoughts, should i change it? When i made the login i used: ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = ? OR emailUsers=?;"``` Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Herald Whether there is malicious intent isn't relevant.  Your code will also fail if string values contain reserved characters, like quote marks.  And yes, that type of parameterized query is what I'm referring to... assuming you use the appropriate library to bind those parameters in the next step.

Comment: After that, I use ```$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);``` and then          ```mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);``` and      ```mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);```